# Do insertions inside transactions prevent other threads from inserting with the same PK during operation?

Tags: mysql, concurrency

Say I have a function in this pattern:

```
public void exampleFunc(int key) {
    db_connection.start_transaction();
    db_connection.execute("INSERT INTO table (pk, content) VALUES ({key}, 'placeholder')");
    ## Run some other code
    db_connection.execute("UPDATE table set content = 'Final value' where pk = {key}");
    db_connection.commit();
}
```

If I were to run this code simultaneously in two threads with the same value for key, would the DB throw a primary key collision error at the point of the initial insert or only after both functions have tried to commit? And will the code between the insert and update be allowed to run?

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are using immediate or deferred constraints. Immediate constraints will be checked on each instruction, deferred not until committing. You have to check your database which one are used.

Comment: I'm not actually sure whether this answers my question, I understand that checks are run after each statement unless you defer the checks, what I'm wondering really is whether those integrity checks can "see" rows in other uncommitted transactions

Comment: Maybe it's a bit of a dilemma. I see this as an optimization. If the DBMS already knows that a transaction produces violating data it can tell me as soon as possible giving me the chance to stop work. Otherwise the violating transaction would only succeed if the original one has been rolled back - from the viewpoint of the DBMS I wouldn't expect this a normal behavior.